# Update Panel Issue

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Hi I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong with the Update Panel.  I'm trying to update ajax combobox every time a button is clicked :

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updateddl" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <ajaxToolkit:ComboBox ID="txbPalletNumber" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource4" DataTextField="PalletNumber" DataValueField="PalletNumber" MaxLength="0" style="display: inline;" AutoPostBack="True">
                </ajaxToolkit:ComboBox>
            </ContentTemplate>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

In the aspx.vb button click event I put:

```
updateddl.Update()
```

It is not updating at all. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

All I did was use

```
txbPalletNumber.Databind()
```

in the button click. Works perfectly.